# How to reset the CSS of HTML Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reset JavaScript changed CSS values in HTML elements (without reloading the page)?.

I'm trying to develop an interactive image gallery using jQuery.

Comment: Would be nice to see some of your code. also a jsfiddle

Comment: html id is "main"

Java script

$("#main").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000);

How to reset the main element?
some button clicking or using timer

Comment: Please try to clearify all details inside your question

Comment: Short of fetching the source code with Ajax and parsing it to find out what the original value of the style attribute was, I don't think this is possible. Better to store the old value before you change it.

Comment: `$("#main").css("opacity","")` should remove the inline style, thereby letting any default in your stylesheet take effect again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .....

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to have the initial styles all set via your stylesheet (referencing elements by class, tag, or id as applicable). Don't have the defaults set via inline styles. Because then when you apply inline styles via JS you can reset to the defaults by simply removing the inline styles again - no need to know the previous values.

So taking your example where you set the opacity:

```
$("#main").animate({'opacity':'0'},2000);
```

This causes an inline style to be applied, which you can remove with:

```
$("#main").css('opacity', '');
```

...at which point whatever was in your stylesheet would take effect again.